# What are these abbreviations?

Tags: shortcuts, cpu

can anyone tell me for what these abbreviations stands for?
Coudn't find it on the web.

> Cpu(s):  3.2%us,  0.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.6%id,  0.4%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man top`:

```
   2c. CPU States
       The CPU states are shown in the  Summary  Area.  They  are  always
       shown  as  a  percentage  and are for the time between now and the
       last refresh.

        us  --  User CPU time
          The time the CPU has spent running users'  processes  that  are
          not niced.

        sy  --  System CPU time
          The  time  the  CPU  has  spent running the kernel and its pro‐
          cesses.

        ni  --  Nice CPU time
          The time the CPU has spent running users'  proccess  that  have
          been niced.

        wa  --  iowait
          Amount of time the CPU has been waiting for I/O to complete.

        hi  --  Hardware IRQ
          The  amount  of time the CPU has been servicing hardware inter‐
          rupts.

        si  --  Software Interrupts
          The amount of time the CPU has been servicing  software  inter‐
          rupts.

        st  --  Steal Time
          The  amount  of  CPU  'stolen' from this virtual machine by the
          hypervisor for other tasks (such  as  running  another  virtual
          machine).
```